# Is the Facebook Activity Log available through the Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

We're looking for graph API access to the data represented here:

```
http://www.facebook.com/{user}/allactivity
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no API call available for this. You can achieve bits and pieces of it via FQL queries.